# #define process in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying C++, There is a point about can not understanding about #define addition. The example  code below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define A 0
#define B A+1
#define C 3-B


int main(){
    cout << A << endl;
    cout << B << endl;
    cout << C;
    return 0;
}
```

The result gives A -> 0, B -> 1, C-> 4. How C equal 4 ?

Comment: `#define` is text substitution. It expands to: `cout << 3-A+1;`, which expands to `cout << 3-0+1;` That prints 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the text substitution. `B` expands to `0+1`. `C` expands to `3-0+1` rather than `3-1`.

```
cout << C;
```

Becomes:

```
cout << 3-0+1;
```

Because of order of operations this displays `4` rather than `2`.

An easy way to see this would be to try something like:

```
cout << C * 50;
```

If we operate under the faulty assumption that `C` is actually `4`, we'd expect to see `200`. But because the above is equivalent to:

```
cout << 3-0+1 * 50;
```

Then we correctly see `53`.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` performs simple textual substitution. When you expand `B` out, you get `0+1` in source code, which is *not* necessarily identical to "an integer with the value `1`".

So, in your example code, if we substitute the values in:

```
int main(){
    cout << 0 << endl;
    cout << 0+1 << endl;
    cout << 3-0+1;
    return 0;
}
```

`3 - 0 + 1` is `4`.